# Using same table in a UNION multiple times

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5, db2-9.7

I am given a query that is using the same table with same columns and filters multiple times and the only thing is changing is the Type which is given manually. I am thinking there must be a better way to do that.

Query statement is like below:

```
    Select Column 1, Column 2, Sum(Column 3) AS Test, "First Query" AS "Type"
           From Table X
           Where Column 1 = "Fly"
    Group by Column 1, Column 2
    
    UNION ALL 
    
    Select Column 1, Column 2, Sum(Column 3) AS Test, "Second Query" AS "Type"
           From Table X
           Where Column 1 = "Fly"
    Group by Column 1, Column 2
 
    UNION ALL 
    
    Select Column 1, Column 2, Sum(Column 3) AS Test, "Third Query" AS "Type"
           From Table X
           Where Column 1 = "Fly"
    Group by Column 1, Column 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```sql
Select X.Column1, X.Column2, Sum(X.Column3) AS Test, Types."Type"
From Table X
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT "First Query" AS "Type"
             UNION ALL
             SELECT "Second Query"
             UNION ALL
             SELECT "Third Query" ) AS Types
Where X.Column1 = "Fly"
Group by X.Column1, X.Column2, Types."Type"
```

---

Maybe SELECTs in `Types` needs additional `FROM DUAL` or similar, or DB2 uses some another method for to select scalar value - test.

**UPDATE** (copied from the comment)

> You can shorten the CROSS JOIN part with:
>
> ```sql
> CROSS JOIN ( values ('First Query'),('Second Query'),('Third Query')) types (type)
> ```
>
> FWIW, Db2 also allows
>
> ```sql
> CROSS JOIN ( values 'First Query','Second Query','Third Query') types (type)
> ```
>
> but that's non standard I beleive – [Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart)

Comment: Makes totally sense :)  Thank you! :)

Comment: @Lennart Thanks. Added into the answer.

Comment: @Lennart Thank you!